# How do I list the table names in a database?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

We have an Oracle 8i database on which I have only read access.  We use ODBC and MS Access to read data from that database since we don't have Oracle Client software. This works fine.
I am using ADO.NET with ASP.NET. Now I want to display a list of all the tables that I see in MS Access via ODBC.
I have tried this with ODBC connection in C#.  I am tried the following queries to get the list of tables, which did not work.

1. select table_name from dba_tables;
2. select table_name from all_tables;
3. select tname from tab;

### Please help.

### Thanks for the response.  I tried them without luck.  All I want to see is the same list of tables that are available in MS Access when I use ODBC to create Linked Tables.

This is the function that I am using to achieve this, which does not really work the way I would have liked.

```
public static ArrayList GetODBCTablesList()
        {
            try
            {                
                OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=mydsn;UID=user1;PWD=pwd1;");
                DbConnection.Open();

                OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
                DbCommand.CommandText = "select table_name from all_tables";                
                OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (DbReader != null)
                {
                    ArrayList TableList = new ArrayList();
                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        TableList.Add(DbReader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    DbReader.Close();
                    DbCommand.Dispose();
                    DbConnection.Close();

                    TableList.Sort();
                    TableList.TrimToSize();
                    return TableList;
                }

                DbCommand.Dispose();
                DbConnection.Close();

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHandler.WriteLogMessage(ex.GetBaseException().ToString(), true);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This gives me a list of tables which does not contain all the tables that I see when I link tables in MS Access using ODBC.

Comment: Could you give us some more details on what is not working with query 2?

Comment: Perhaps you should try them again, but this time, *with luck*.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
select table_name from tabs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try
 `select table_name from user_tables`

or

`select object_name from USER_objects where object_type='TABLE'`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using ADO.NET, I would suggest to use [OdbcConnection.GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135851%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method returns a `DataTable` containing information about the schema of your database.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986360/542417), this might work for you:

> OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables")

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
```

Taken from [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/oracle-get-list-of-all-tables)

Comment: I read something about dba_tables being subject to permissions of some sort. But I don't recall the exact nature of that.